# Using other website's image source with HTML Link in my PHP website

Tags: php, html

If the other website's image file size is equal to 100mb and i am using that source in my website, does my website's server lose 100mb of bandwidth when a client loads that image?

If no, then what is the bandwidth limit using other website's image source with HTML link?

I ask this because if i use other website's image then their administrator change their image to 100mb image size, it may ruin my server when many clients load that image already

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming tools or programming languages.

Comment: It is a base knowledge of HTML. Your page is only the .html and this will be downloaded from your webserver. All links inside it will be downloaded from the respective webservers.

Comment: I am using a PHP website. I do not use any .html

Comment: @nothingn The PHP generates the HTML that the browser renders.

Comment: Yes, if your image provider sets a limit to 100MB download a day, your users will no longer see that image once their combined views exceed that amount of data. If your provider sets  a limit to 100MBit/s and there are thousands of visitors, then some of them might not see the images either

Comment: Any administrator can change their image to huge image file size so i am not using other website's image source anymore since no one answers correctly

Answer (score 2):

On your website, you will only store the link to the image as part of your HTML code. The loading of the image will be done on the client side, directly from the server storing the image, thus it won't have anything to do with your bandwidth.

Be also careful not to confuse the bandwidth (basically your 'internet speed') and the storage (the space you have on the server).

Comment: I would have answered exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Images are loaded to your clients' browsers, not your server, so it will not use your server's bandwidth. Only the files that are served from your domain will take your bandwidth.